# Access ASP.NET Master Page DropDownList Control in the Master Page's Code Behind

Tags: asp.net, controls, master-pages, code-behind

I have a master page with a dropdownlist control on it. In the code behind of the said master page, I want to access the dropdownlist control and assign a data source to it. Below is the source code of the master page:

```
  <section id="login">
<asp:LoginView runat="server" ViewStateMode="Disabled">
` <AnonymousTemplate>
       <ul>
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Report Category"></asp:Label>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="CountriesDropDownList" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
      </ul>
    </AnonymousTemplate>
```

Below is what I want to do in the code behind file.

```
CountriesDropDownList.DataSource = "myDataSource";
```

Comment: So what is your issue? What problem you are facing?

Comment: Source code is missing

Comment: Are you not able to use `CountriesDropDownList` in the code behind?

Comment: No please.  When I type this, the countriesDropDownList does not show in the intellisense

Comment: I am using visual studio 2013

Comment: Are you able to get intellsense on Label1 ?

Answer (score 0):

You want to access this dropdownlist on your content page, right?

You could try:

```
this.Master.CountriesDropDownList.DataSource = "myDataSource";
```

or check this out: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xxwa0ff0.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Create a string property in **master's code behind:**

```
public string CountriesDropDownListDataSource
{
    get {
        return this.CountriesDropDownList.DataSource;
    }
    set {
        this.CountriesDropDownList.DataSource= value;
    }
}
```

To set the datasource do this:

```
var myMaster = this.Master as YourMasterType;
if(myMaster != null)
{
    myMaster.CountriesDropDownListDataSource = "myDataSource";
}
```

Or directly from the masterpage

```
this.CountriesDropDownListDataSource = "myDataSource";
```